# Rails 3 Submitting a form with Javascript causes html response instead of a AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, dom-events

When I submit a form with Javascript I get the html response, it is like it ignores the remote true parameter.  If I submit the form with the submit button it does the AJAX and updates the page elements requested.  So the only difference in the code is the presence of the `onchange` parameter and the button.  Here is my code for the form:

```
<% form_tag('switch_car', :method => :put, :name => "switch_car", :remote => true) do %>
<div class="field">
    <label>Car Name:</label>
    <%= select_tag(:id, options_from_collection_for_select(active_cars, "id", "name"), :onchange => "submitForm('switch_car')", :include_blank => true)%>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Here is my Javascript function: just a simple submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
function submitForm(formname){
    document.switch_car.submit();
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML generated:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="switch_car" data-remote="true" method="post" name="switch_car"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="PEbdqAoiik37lcoP4+v+dakpYxdpMkSm7Ub8eZpdF9I=" /></div><div class="field"> 
    <label>Car Name:</label> 
    <select id="id" name="id" onchange="submitForm('switch_car')"><option value=""></option><option value="9">Truck</option> 
<option value="10">Car</option></select> 
</div>
```

Anybody know why the Javascript submit causes a different result than the button on the same form?  If so can I get the Javascript submit to work with an Ajax result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  I thought submitting the form with javascript would submit the form with the same remote => true option but it appears to bypass that.  I had to submit using new AjaxRequest to get it working.